# Users ignore filled in input fields, outdated info pour in

Tags: usability

We have a form on our loan application page, on which we take personal and work related information from loan applicants.

Users who fill the form are logged in, so we know who they are and fill input fields beforehand with current user data recorded on our database.

However, we find out that some part of the user info we pre-fill on forms are outdated, such as work telephone number and work address. But we learn whether it is outdated or not, just after the form is submitted, when we try calling employers of the applicant.

Our assumption is that, the outdated information is a result of users neglecting pre-filled form fields.

So we are to decide, to continue with prefilled fields and finding a UI solution to make people feel the urge to review and update prefilled fields if necessary, or empty some fields (work info) and require users to type their work phone number and address during application if the user's data on our database is older than, say 12 months or so, which looks like huge effort for the applicants whose work info is already up-to-date and while we are trying to make our application process simpler, shorter in general.

What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than displaying the existing data in form fields, display it in an uneditable state and ask them to confirm that it's up-to-date. This gets the user to actually check what's already been entered. If they say that it's out of date, turn it in to the pre-populated form.

Depending on how your form is structured you may want to show all of the preexisting data in one place with a single confirmation option, or split it up in to the correct sections.

Example:

[image: Choice]